# Using PHP & MYSQL database, how can I tally up a score from a quiz?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am having an issue with my quiz for uni and I have searched for many possible solutions but none of which suit my needs. I have my quiz running off a database and my problem lies in the **Results** page. At the end of the quiz, the last question is captured on the following page however the total correct answers are not displaying, it only shows "1/6". I thought maybe it was displaying the amount of incorrect answers but I have tested this theory a few times and that is not the case.

Here is the code to my results page:

```
<?php session_start();
//connect to the database
include('connectDB.php');

//has the user selected a radio button
if (isset($_REQUEST['value']))
{
    {
        $_SESSION['total']+= $_REQUEST['value'];
    }     
}
else
{
    //No value inputted from the user
    echo "Please select an answer";
    $id--;
}

//collecting the answers and tallying the score
$question = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'tblquiz';");
$x = 0;
$score = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($question))
{
    echo $row['questions'].'<br/>';

    $answered = $row['answer'.$_POST['value'.$x]];
    $correct = $row['value'];

    if($answered == $correct)
    {
        $score++;
        $acolor = 'green';
    }

    else
    {
        $acolor = 'red';
    }

    echo 'You answered <font color='.$acolor.'>'.$answered.'<font color=black> <br/>';

    echo 'The correct answer was '.$correct.'<br/>';
    echo '----------------------------------- <br/>';

    $x = $x + 1;
}



echo 'Your score is '.$score.'/'.$x;
mysql_close($db);
?>
```

Now some of the variables in this code probably don't need to be there but I have been trying different solutions and this is the most recent one that I have tried.

Any help will be greatly appreciated and if possible ASAP!

Thank you.

**Updated Code**

Here is the updated version of my code so far:

```
<?php session_start();
//connect to the database
include('connectDB.php');

//has the user selected a radio button
if (isset($_REQUEST['value']))
{
    {
        $_SESSION['total']+= $_REQUEST['value'];
    }     
}
else
{
    //No value inputted from the user
    echo "Please select an answer";
    $id--;
}

//collecting the answers and tallying the score
$question = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblquiz");
$x = 0;
$score = 0;

echo '<h1>Results</h1>';

var_dump($row);
var_dump($_POST[$row]);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($question))
{
    echo $row['questions'].'<br/>';

    $answered = $_POST['value'.$x];
    $correct = $row['value'.$x];

    if($answered == $correct)
    { //displays the correct answer in green
        $score++;
        $acolor = 'green';
    }

    else
    { //displays the wrong answer in red
        $acolor = 'red';
    }

    //users' chosen answer
    echo 'You answered <font color='.$acolor.'>'.$answered.'<font color=black> <br/>';
    //correct answer
    echo 'The correct answer was '.$correct.'<br/>';
    echo '----------------------------------- <br/>';

    $x = $x + 1;
}


echo '<p><strong>Your score is '.$score.'/'.$x.'</strong>';
mysql_close($db);

?>
```

`var_dump($row);` and `var_dump($_POST[$row]);` both gave an output of **NULL**

Comment: Are the colours correct? There are a few things _wrong_ with your code; most notably, you shouldn't have the semicolon in your query. Have you tried a `var_dump($row)`? What's your table structure?

Comment: @Steven At this stage I'm not really fussed about the colours, I don't really need them, it was just something I tried to see if it worked. Thank you for that I have taken out the semicolon in the query.I have tried the `var_dump($row)` and it came up with NULL. 

My table structure is:
ques_id, question, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, value1, value2, value3, value4

The values listed are INT as they hold the points for each question.

Comment: Okay, I missed this in my first comment! Try: `SELECT * FROM tblquiz` you shouldn't use single/double quotes around _table names_ and _field names_ you can use back ticks `\``

Comment: Thank you so much for that tip! Ok, so now, the **answers** are not being echoed and I purposely clicked a wrong answer for one question but the score shows up as all correct.

Comment: What is this line `$answered = $row['answer'.$_POST['value'.$x]];` supposed to be doing?

Comment: That should be the answer the user chose. So where it says, `echo 'You answered <font color='.$acolor.'>'.$answered.'<font color=black> <br/>';` it should display the users' chosen answer and then right under it the correct answer will display.

Comment: Okay, I think that you have inadvertently _messed up_ (either that or **I** misunderstand how your system works). Anyway, should it not be `$answered = $_POST['value'.$x];` and the following line be `$correct = $row['value'.$x];`?

Comment: To be honest, I found some of the code through another question that was asked by someone else and I was trying it out to see if it worked. Obviously doesn't work very well for my quiz but I had to give it a go. I tried your theory and the quiz now displays the values next to "the correct answer was..." Also, the calculation is off. I can upload the new code underneath the original above if it helps to see it rather than remembering what has been changed.

Comment: Yeah that would be helpful. Can you also post the output of `var_dump($_POST);` and `var_dump($row);` (just one for `$row`)?

Comment: Updated code is available now

Comment: Okay they returned `NULL` because that's not what/where I meant (my fault for not being clear). Anyway, can you copy/paste this line, _exactly_: `var_dump($row); var_dump($_POST); exit;` above this line: `echo $row['questions'].'<br/>';` i.e. it should be the first line in your `while` loop; It should return 2 arrays, then copy/paste them in the question.